# Get number of created blocks in a day in Quorum

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, blocks, quorum

I'm looking for a query to query Quorum node to get the number of blocks created in a day. Is there any direct query to do the same?

Also, how to iterate over each created block to check the number of transactions in it. Is there any query?

Thanks.